# Error: error during read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, telnet, netcat

I have openocd running and am sending a simple reset command to my board.
However I am getting this error:

**Info : accepting 'telnet' connection from 4444**

**Error: error during read: Connection reset by peer**

**Info : dropped 'telnet' connection**

Here is the basic script.

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 4444))
clientsocket.send('reset')
```

Using the command line `nc localhost 4444 <<EOF reset EOF` it works fine. So  my openocd connection is working

Answer (score 0):

Your try using a here document on the command line works fine because the `reset` command is followed by a `\n` character, which the `send('reset')` lacks. Correct: `send('reset\n')`.